# Is it better to have a single, more general directive or multiple type based directives in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it considered good practice to have:

1. Single, general directive that has multiple data-* parameters and serial data is binded from controller
2. Single, general directive that has config and serial data is  from controller
3. Multiple directives that has some pre-defined config inside directive,   some of config is by data-* parameters and serial data is binded from controller

For example, I have a template were I need to create ~16 charts (Highcharts/amCharts). All of them won't have the same configuration and serial data.

Example of 1 option:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('ngHighcharts', () => ({
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, $elem, $attrs) {

      var chart, config;
      config = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: $elem[0],
          type: $attrs.type ? $attrs.type : 'bar'
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: $attrs.exporting ? $attrs.exporting : false
        },
        title: {
          text: $attrs.title ? $attrs.title : ''
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: $attrs.categories ? $attrs.categories : data[0]
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: $attrs.valueSuffix ? $attrs.valueSuffix : ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: $attrs.dataLabels ? $attrs.dataLabels : false
            }
          }
        },
        series: scope.data
      };

      chart = new Highcharts.Chart(config);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        scope.$evalAsync(function () {
          chart.destroy ();
        });
      });

    }
   }));
```

Example of 2 option:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('ngHighcharts', () => ({
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      config: '=',
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, $elem, $attrs) {

      config.chart.renderTo = $elem[0];
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(config);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        scope.$evalAsync(function () {
          chart.destroy ();
        });
      });

    }
   }));
```

Example of 3 option:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('ngHighcharts', () => ({
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, $elem, $attrs) {

      var chart, config;
      config = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: $elem[0],
          type: 'bar'
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: true
        },
        title: {
          text: $attrs.title ? $attrs.title : ''
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: $attrs.categories ? $attrs.categories : data[0]
        },
        tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: $attrs.valueSuffix ? $attrs.valueSuffix : ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        },
        series: scope.data
      };

      chart = new Highcharts.Chart(config);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        scope.$evalAsync(function () {
          chart.destroy ();
        });
      });

    }
   }));
```

What would be considered best practice in this situation?

Comment: This might be a better question for programmers.stackexchange.com or codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This might be somewhat opinion based but I would say this is more a question of 1. How much is shared by each type of chart. VS 2. How unique is each one. One thing that would be good practice though is if you are going to do a directive with a lot of data attributes it might be better to restrict it to only elements rather then elements and attributes that way you don't have the possibility of conflicting attributes. After you reduce the risk of conflicting elements and attributes it is more just based on what works best for your situation.

Comment: @SunilD. when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)